# Why does this polynomial splits over $\Bbb{F}_2(\sqrt{X})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field

I have the following problem:

> Let $k=\Bbb{F}_2(X)$ and $E=\Bbb{F}_2(\sqrt{X})$. Then I know that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{X}$ over $k$ is $t^2-X$. But now in the lecture our prof. says that this polynomial splits into $(t-\sqrt{X})^2$ over $E$ and thus only has one root.

But I somehow don't see why it splits into $(t-\sqrt{X})^2$ and not into $(t-\sqrt{X})(t+\sqrt{X})$. As I know it we define $$\Bbb{F}_2(\sqrt{X})=\{a+b\sqrt{X}:a,b\in \Bbb{F}_2\}$$ Then I would say that $-\sqrt{X}$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{X}$ since $[-1]=[1]$ in $\Bbb{F}_2$ but I'm not
sure if this is enought to conclude that $(t-\sqrt{X})(t+\sqrt{X})=(t-\sqrt{X})^2$.

Could someone maybe help me.

Comment: Since the coefficients are in $\mathbb{F}_2$, one has $-1=1$

Comment: In the field $\Bbb{F}_2$ we have $-1=1$, so therefore $\sqrt{X}=-\sqrt{X}$ in the extension field. After the beginners' course we begin to abbreviate $n=n\cdot1$ for all integers $n$. Here $n\cdot1$ means the sum of $n$ copies of $1$, where $1=1_R$ is the multiplicative neutral element of the ring $R$ in question. Using those principles $1_{\Bbb{F}_2}=[1]$ can be more simply written as $-1$. There is some notational abuse going on. But, unless you become familiar enough with this, you will have a hard time working with fields like $\Bbb{F}_p(X)$.

Comment: Do observe *the role* of integers in this. We can equate $n$ and $n\cdot[1]$ as elements of $\Bbb{F}_p$, and hence elements of its extension rings. But that does not mean that we could to the same when an integer appears in the exponent. So, for example, in the field $\Bbb{F}_2(X)$ the element $X^3$ is **not** the same element as $X^{[3]}$. The latter makes no sense, because we cannot (easily) define a power $a^b$ unless $b$ is an integer (as opposed to an element of some other ring).

Comment: ah okey thanks, so the most important observation for the moment is that $-1=1$ in $\Bbb{F}_2$ and then we are done right?

Comment: Correct, Wave!!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen perfect thanks!